# How to build a gradle jar from a github library

Tags: java, gradle, jar, okhttp

I have attempted to rebuild the jar for https://github.com/square/okhttp library. However, this is the error I get after first cloning it and then calling "gradle assemble". Is there something incorrect about my method?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/test/okhttptest/okhttp/build.gradle' line: 75
- What went wrong:
  Plugin [id: 'ru.vyarus.animalsniffer', version: '1.5.1'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'ru.vyarus.animalsniffer:ru.vyarus.animalsniffer.gradle.plugin:1.5.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 617ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is that you are using a locally installed gradle version since your call is "gradle assemble". your gradle version is propably too old so you it can't handle the plugin.

This repository has a gradle-wrapper (gradlew) checked in.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

change your call into ./gradlew assemble and the wrapper will handle the download of the required gradle version and will handle all the dependencies for you.